# Error slint React

Tags: reactjs

Saludos solicito ayuda elimando los errores de slint
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he buscado mucho pero no obtengo respuesta, les agradeceria mucho la ayuda.

Comment: Que has buscado? El problema está escrito ahí, dice que está mal indentado.

Comment: si lo que pasa es que me interpreta como error los espacios lo cual no deberia ser así

Comment: parecer ser alguna configuracion del slint